# Form Overlay in WPF showing behind window

Tags: c#, wpf, forms

I have a WPF window that spawns a custom usercontrol

```
owner = Window.GetWindow(placementTarget);

form = new Form();
form.Opacity = owner.Opacity;
form.ShowInTaskbar = false;
form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
System.Drawing.Size size = new System.Drawing.Size(Convert.ToInt32(placementTarget.ActualWidth), Convert.ToInt32(placementTarget.ActualHeight));
form.ClientSize = size;
webBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
form.Controls.Add(webBrowser);

Cursor.Hide();

Point location = placementTarget.TransformToAncestor(owner).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
form.Left = Convert.ToInt32(location.X + owner.Left);
form.Top = Convert.ToInt32(location.Y + owner.Top);

DependencyPropertyDescriptor descriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(UIElement.OpacityProperty, typeof(Window));
descriptor.AddValueChanged(owner, delegate { form.Opacity = owner.Opacity; });
```

This displays the form, and I can see it if I move the left property of the form to a negative value so that my main window is not covering it.

For some reason though, I cannot seem to get this form to show up ontop of the window. Any ideas?

Cheers.

Comment: If `Form` is a `Window`, then you can try using the [`Window.Owner` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner(v=vs.110).aspx): `form.Owner = owner;` Or you could try the [`Window.Topmost` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.topmost(v=vs.110).aspx): `form.TopMost = true;` If it's not, then try that on the `Window` that you display it in.

Comment: No luck, tried setting the wpf window to false and the form to true but with no avail.

Comment: What is placementTarget?

Comment: Where's the code that *actually* shows the `Window`?